# C How read() function read from STDERR?

Tags: c, bash, input, pipe, stderr

I got the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
        char buf[10];
        read(2,buf,4);
}
```

As far as I know, read() function now will read from the file descriptor 2 which is Stderr. When I compiled and executed it using following command:

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

In the terminal it prompts me to type the input like it does with Stdin. Why is that? And how could I send the stderr to the file using pipe in bash? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `STDERR_FILENO` is an *output* file descriptor. You can't read from it. If you check what `read` *returns* (which you should always do!) you should probably be getting either an error (`-1`) or end-of-file (`0`). What is the real problem you're having? *Why* do you want to read from standard error?

Comment: As for piping in the shell, [a manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) should be useful.

Comment: As for how to redirect stdout/stderr in bash, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: on most UNIX-like systems, you can write to standard input and read from standard output and standard error when the relevant file descriptor is connected to the terminal.  Try it!  You're not intended to do it, but it does typically work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry for piling on (Jonathan Leffler already said this), but: you're wrong. (And it looks like at least thee other people, who upvoted your comment, share the same misbelief.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I kind of understand why it happened like that now. But I'm doing a challenge which requires me to input a string, say `abcd`, to that particular `read(2,buf,4)` function and I still have not figured it out. How to do it?

Comment: You can type it at the terminal; you could run `./your_prog 2<somefile` to redirect 'standard error' (file descriptor 2) so it is opened for input from `somefile`.  There are probably other devious ways to achieve the result.

Comment: @SteveSummit I admit defeat when I have to... :) But it's still not something one should do, and we still don't know why the OP wants to read from the "output" file? If the program is part of a pipe, then the piped input would be sent to the standard *input* file instead. It seems to me that the OP needs to learn about pipes, instead of just guessing blindly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think the OP "wants" to read from stderr as part of any practical program.  It's pretty clear the posted code is part of some puzzle or challenge, that's deliberately devious as opposed to useful.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Yes it is a puzzle and with @JonathanLeffler 's suggestion I can do it now :)

Answer (score 2):

Because when you run the program directly from command-line, **both its stdin and stderr are connected to the same file** (your terminal) **that it has read access to**. So it simply reads from the terminal, but not necessarily its stderr. When you redirect its stderr, everything fails.

Here's my test.

```
ibug@linux:~ $ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
        char b[10];
        printf("%ld\n", read(2, b, 10));
        return 0;
}
ibug@linux:~ $ gcc t.c
ibug@linux:~ $ ./a.out
abcdefg
8
ibug@linux:~ $ ./a.out 2>/dev/null
-1
ibug@linux:~ $ ./a.out 2>/dev/zero
-1
ibug@linux:~ $
```

Comment: Why did it only fail when I redirect its stderr?

Comment: @Wolfat Not sure. Reading from an output descriptor itself is an undefined behavior.

Comment: I see. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

#### File descriptors

One of the many historical quirks of Unix-based systems is that the code that opens a terminal for use by a session typically works like this (in effect, and ignoring error checking):

```
close(0);
open(tty_name, O_RDWR);
close(1);
dup(0);
close(2);
dup(0);
…
execv(shell[0], shell);
```

On success, the `open()` system call returns the lowest available file descriptor.  After closing file descriptor 0, the subsequent open opens file descriptor 0 (standard input), and the terminal is opened for read and write.  Then file descriptors 1 (standard output) and 2 (standard error) are duplicated from the read/write descriptor 0.  Thus, all three standard file descriptors are, by default, open for both reading and writing.  Note the use of the term 'file descriptors'!

As a consequence, a program can usually write to file descriptor 0 and read from either file descriptor 1 or 2 (or both).  If you're using file streams (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`), you may run into problems, but the underlying file descriptors are often read-write when they're connected to the terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

static void check_fd(int fd)
{
    char buffer[1024];

    err_remark("About to read from fd = %d\n", fd);
    ssize_t nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (nbytes < 0)
        err_sysrem("Failed to read fd = %d: ", fd);
    else if (nbytes == 0)
        err_remark("Got EOF (0 bytes read) on fd = %d\n", fd);
    else
    {
        err_remark("Got normal read of %d bytes on fd = %d\n", (int)nbytes, fd);
        printf("Data: [%.*s]\n", (int)nbytes - 1, buffer);
    }

    err_remark("About to write to fd = %d\n", fd);
    char message[] = "  'Twas brillig and the the slithy toves\n"
                     "  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.\n"
                     "  All mimsy were the borogroves,\n"
                     "  And the mome raths outgrabe.\n";
    nbytes = write(fd, message, sizeof(message) - 1);
    if (nbytes < 0)
        err_sysrem("Failed to write to fd = %d: ", fd);
    else if (nbytes == (ssize_t)sizeof(message) - 1)
        err_remark("Successfully wrote %d bytes to fd = %d\n", (int)nbytes, fd);
    else
        err_remark("Got a short write (%d bytes written; %d expected) on fd = %d\n",
                   (int)nbytes, (int)(sizeof(message) - 1), fd);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 0)
        err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    check_fd(STDIN_FILENO);
    check_fd(STDOUT_FILENO);
    check_fd(STDERR_FILENO);
    return 0;
}
```

This code uses my preferred error reporting functions, which are
available on GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack
Overflow Questions) repository as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the
[src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq)
sub-directory.

Sample runs:

```
$ ./stdio11
stdio11: About to read from fd = 0
This is typed at the terminal.
stdio11: Got normal read of 31 bytes on fd = 0
Data: [This is typed at the terminal.]
stdio11: About to write to fd = 0
  'Twas brillig and the the slithy toves
  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
  All mimsy were the borogroves,
  And the mome raths outgrabe.
stdio11: Successfully wrote 140 bytes to fd = 0
stdio11: About to read from fd = 1
More terminal typing.
stdio11: Got normal read of 22 bytes on fd = 1
Data: [More terminal typing.]
stdio11: About to write to fd = 1
  'Twas brillig and the the slithy toves
  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
  All mimsy were the borogroves,
  And the mome raths outgrabe.
stdio11: Successfully wrote 140 bytes to fd = 1
stdio11: About to read from fd = 2
The last line of input from the terminal for this process.
stdio11: Got normal read of 59 bytes on fd = 2
Data: [The last line of input from the terminal for this process.]
stdio11: About to write to fd = 2
  'Twas brillig and the the slithy toves
  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
  All mimsy were the borogroves,
  And the mome raths outgrabe.
stdio11: Successfully wrote 140 bytes to fd = 2
$
```

And:

```
$ ./stdio11 </dev/null >output
stdio11: About to read from fd = 0
stdio11: Got EOF (0 bytes read) on fd = 0
stdio11: About to write to fd = 0
stdio11: Failed to write to fd = 0: error (9) Bad file descriptor
stdio11: About to read from fd = 1
stdio11: Failed to read fd = 1: error (9) Bad file descriptor
stdio11: About to write to fd = 1
stdio11: Successfully wrote 140 bytes to fd = 1
stdio11: About to read from fd = 2
Standard error is still the terminal, so input can still occur here.
stdio11: Got normal read of 69 bytes on fd = 2
stdio11: About to write to fd = 2
  'Twas brillig and the the slithy toves
  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
  All mimsy were the borogroves,
  And the mome raths outgrabe.
stdio11: Successfully wrote 140 bytes to fd = 2
$ cat output
  'Twas brillig and the the slithy toves
  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
  All mimsy were the borogroves,
  And the mome raths outgrabe.
Data: [Standard error is still the terminal, so input can still occur here.]
$
```

JFTR: The test above was done on a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 (and using GCC 7.2.0), but I'd expect the same results on any Unix-based machine.

#### File streams

The standard I/O file streams use the file descriptors 0, 1, 2 but they are not configured to allow output on `stdin` or input on either `stdout` or `stderr` — which is what you'd expect given the names of the streams.

Here is analogous test code using file streams (`FILE *`) instead of descriptors:

```
/* SO 4844-3136 - file streams version A */
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

static void check_fp(FILE *fp, const char *name)
{
    char buffer[1024];

    err_remark("About to read from %s\n", name);
    size_t nbytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), fp);
    if (nbytes <= 0)
        err_sysrem("Failed to read %s: ", name);
    else
    {
        err_remark("Got normal read of %zu bytes on %s\n", nbytes, name);
        printf("Data: [%.*s]\n", (int)nbytes - 1, buffer);
    }

    err_remark("About to write to %s\n", name);
    char message[] = "  'Twas brillig and the the slithy toves\n"
                     "  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.\n"
                     "  All mimsy were the borogroves,\n"
                     "  And the mome raths outgrabe.\n";
    nbytes = fwrite(message, sizeof(char), sizeof(message) - 1, fp);
    if (nbytes == 0)
        err_sysrem("Failed to write to %s: ", name);
    else if (nbytes == sizeof(message) - 1)
        err_remark("Successfully wrote %d bytes to %s\n", (int)nbytes, name);
    else
        err_remark("Got a short write (%zu bytes written; %zu expected) on %s\n",
                   nbytes, (sizeof(message) - 1), name);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 0)
        err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    check_fp(stdin,  "stdin");
    check_fp(stdout, "stdout");
    check_fp(stderr, "stderr");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$  stdio13
stdio13: About to read from stdin
Hello, and welcome to the wonderful world of Unix.
Interestingly, the fread() function does not return when 
the input reaches the end of a line.  It continues reading
until the total amount of data entered, newlines and all,
is longer than the buffer it is given to read.  That is 
quite surprising in many ways.  However, such is life.
The test was run on a Mac with macOS 10.13.3, using GCC
7.3.0, which was released today, Friday 2018-01-26.  The
build on macOS was interesting; it had to be restarted
multiple times because headers were missing (when running
"make -j8").  Maybe the parallelism confused it?  Who knows!
It is hard to tell.  There are new versions of MPC and MPFR
that can be used, too.  Grump!  It takes a while to type as
much as 1024 bytes of data.  Let's see: at 64 characters
per line, that would be 16 lines.  And this is line 15.
We should soon be done - though the lines may not all be as
long as 64 bytes.  In fact, none of them is 64 bytes long.
But they're close to 60 bytes each, so it won't take much
stdio13: Got normal read of 1024 bytes on stdin
Data: [Hello, and welcome to the wonderful world of Unix.
Interestingly, the fread() function does not return when
the input reaches the end of a line.  It continues reading
until the total amount of data entered, newlines and all,
is longer than the buffer it is given to read.  That is
quite surprising in many ways.  However, such is life.
The test was run on a Mac with macOS 10.13.3, using GCC
7.3.0, which was released today, Friday 2018-01-26.  The
build on macOS was interesting; it had to be restarted
multiple times because headers were missing (when running
"make -j8").  Maybe the parallelism confused it?  Who knows!
It is hard to tell.  There are new versions of MPC and MPFR
that can be used, too.  Grump!  It takes a while to type as
much as 1024 bytes of data.  Let's see: at 64 characters
per line, that would be 16 lines.  And this is line 15.
We should soon be done - though the lines may not all be as
long as 64 bytes.  In fact, none of them is 64 bytes long.
But they're close to 60 bytes each, so it won't ]
stdio13: About to write to stdin
stdio13: Failed to write to stdin: error (9) Bad file descriptor
stdio13: About to read from stdout
stdio13: Failed to read stdout: error (9) Bad file descriptor
stdio13: About to write to stdout
  'Twas brillig and the the slithy toves
  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
  All mimsy were the borogroves,
  And the mome raths outgrabe.
stdio13: Successfully wrote 140 bytes to stdout
stdio13: About to read from stderr
stdio13: Failed to read stderr: error (9) Bad file descriptor
stdio13: About to write to stderr
  'Twas brillig and the the slithy toves
  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
  All mimsy were the borogroves,
  And the mome raths outgrabe.
stdio13: Successfully wrote 140 bytes to stderr
$
```

This shows quite clearly that you can't write to `stdin` or read from `stdout` or `stderr`, at least on a Mac.

You can find this code on GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack
Overflow Questions) repository in the
[src/so-4844-3136](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-4844-3136)
sub-directory.  There's also a variant `stdio17.c` that uses `fgets()` and `fputs()`, but that's less satisfactory in some respects because the I/O functions do not report the length of the inputs or outputs, unlike `fread()` and `fwrite()` — but `fgets()` stops reading at the first newline, unlike `fread()`.